# Function Type with more than one unnamed function

Tags: typescript

The scenario is two **function types** defined by the same interface.

```
type InterfaceB<R, S> = (param1: S, param2: R) => R;
interface InterfaceA<S> {
    <R>(action: R): R;
}
interface InterfaceA<S> {
    <R>(action: InterfaceB<R, S>): R;
}
const x: InterfaceA<string> = (): InterfaceA<string> => {
    var a1: (action: number) => number = (action: number) => { return 1; };
    var a2: (action: (p: string, p2: number) => number) => number = (action: (p: string, p2: number) => number) => { return 2; };
    return { a1, a2 } as any;
};


const result = x("This should take the (action:R) signature since it's a single value")
console.log(result);
```

The code compiles, but there are few issues:

1. Is there a way to avoid the cast `as any`?
2. When `x` is invoked, VsCode shows the right two overloads, however, neither of the two functions are invoked and the result is an object literal with the two objects (which make kind of sense since this is what I am returning). What is the change required?

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate what are you trying to achieve? What is the expected output/behavior? Also defining generic parameter and not using it doesn't make any sense (first function `interface InterfaceA<S> {
    <R>(action: R): R;
}`)

Comment: This example is a simplified version of Redux Dispatch. If you look at the index.d.ts you will see that Dispath<T> is using a generic the same way (without using the T directly). The example is also a simplification of Redux's Dispatch in a combination of Redux-Thunk library that is adding to the definition file of Redux a second definition on Dispatch.

Comment: Actually Redux's `Dispatch<D>` uses its type parameter `D` in the constraint `<A extends D>`:
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/index.d.ts

Comment: After removing the `as any` cast, the compiler error is `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'a1' does not exist in type 'InterfaceA<string>'.`

Comment: Dispatch changed in the definition file about 2 months ago. You are right now, but for many months was like I am describing. https://github.com/reactjs/redux/commit/4509938c9ad76d9905aeb5d3002741efb26b0ee4#diff-b52768974e6bc0faccb7d4b75b162c99
It's also not in the official npm package and will be released soon.
Thanks Robert, I know, I am trying to find a way to fix that issue :P

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of such an interface can be a single function which changes its behavior according to input parameter type. For example:

```
const x: InterfaceA<string> = (action) => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
        return 2;
    }
    return 1;
};
```